# How mutable should EventArgs be? C#

Tags: c#, immutability, eventargs

For classes which derive from `EventArgs`, how mutable should their data be?

I know there might be a case of "it depends", but since the object is potentially getting passed around a lot, it makes me think that it should be as immutable as possible:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public MyEventArgs(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on use case - some event args are cancellable so they need to be mutable (e.g. say you can navigate, you might want to make your navigate event args cancellable). Make your own decision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, members of your custom EventArgs class are used to return information back to the event caller (to the object which owns / triggers the event).

In that cases, the member should be editable.

One prominent example is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Huh, I was going to comment about linking to a derived class when the property is defined on the base, but surprisingly, `KeyEventArgs` *doesn't* derive from [`HandledEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.handledeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is probably a slightly more widely used version of a `Handled` property.